# optimize elasticsearch / JVM

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, jvm, benchmarking, server

I have a website for classified. For this I'm using elasticsearch, postgres and rails on a same ubuntu 14.04 dedicated server, with 256GB of RAM and 20 cores, 40 threads.

I have 10 indexes on elasticsearch, each have default numbers of shards (5). They have between 1000 and 400 000 classifieds depending on which index.
approximately 5000 requests per minute, 2/3 making an elasticsearch request.

according to htop, jvm is using around 500% of CPU 
I try different options, I reduce number of shards per index, I also try to change JAVA_OPTS as followed

```
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseParNewGC"
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC"

#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=75"
#JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseCMSInitiatingOccupancyOnly"

JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -XX:+UseG1GC"
```

but it doesn't seems to change anything.

so to questions :

- when you change any setting on elasticsearch,  and then restart, should the improvement (if any) be visible immediately or can it arrive a bit later thanks to cache or anything else ?
- can any one help me to find good configuration for JVM / elasticsearch so it will not take that many resources

Comment: What's your ES_HEAP_SIZE setting?

Comment: Ive tried several value for heap, between 26 and 32, but I didnt see any difference.

Comment: Try setting it to ES_HEAP_SIZE=32g That should give the JVM a bit of heap to work with.

Answer (score 2):

First, it's a horrible idea to run your web server, database *and* Elasticsearch server all on the same box. Each of these should be given it's own box, at least. In the case of Elasticsearch, it's actually recommended to have at least 3 servers, or nodes. That way you end up with a load balanced cluster that won't run into [split-brain](http://blog.trifork.com/2013/10/24/how-to-avoid-the-split-brain-problem-in-elasticsearch/) issues.

Further, sharding only makes sense in a cluster. If you only have one node, then all the shards reside on the same node. This causes two performance problems. First, you get the hit that sharding always adds. For every query, Elasticsearch must query each shard individually (each is a separate Lucene index). Then, it must combine and process the result from all the shards to produce the final result. That's a not insignificant amount of overhead. Second, because all the shards reside on the same node, you're I/O-locked. The shards have to be queried one at a time instead of all at once. Optimally, you should have one shard per node, however, since you can't create more shards without reindexing, it's common to have a few extra hanging around for future horizontal scaling. In that scenario, the cost of reindexing what could be 100's of gigs of data or more outweighs a little bit of performance bottleneck. However, if you've got 5 shards running one node, that's probably a large part of your performance problems right there.

Finally, and again, with Elasticsearch in particular, swapping is a huge no-no. Most of what makes Elasticsearch efficient is it's cache which all resides in RAM. If swaps occur, it jacks with the cache in sometimes unpredictable ways. As result, it's recommended to turn off swapping completely on the box your node(s) run on, and set Elasticsearch/JVM to have a min and max memory consumption of roughly half the available RAM of the box. That's virtually impossible to achieve if you have other things running on it like a web server or database. Databases in particular aggressively consume RAM in order to increase throughput, which is why those should likewise reside on their own servers.

Comment: hi, thanks for all this information.
If I could, I would for sure take 3 server, but infortunatly I cant. It is a website which is ttally free, I just makesome money with few banner, just enough to pay for one server. 
I ve just rebuild my indexex with 2 shards (of I read that one will be primary and one replica), but it now seems to be slower . Did I miss  something ?
For swap, it seems to be not swapping according to htop

Comment: You have an extremely beefy server. You could easily divide that out into a handful of smaller servers and actually gain better performance overall. If you set up on something like Azure, you could greatly minimize your costs and deploy only the resources you need, instead of potentially wasting resources that may not be in use 24/7. For Elasticsearch, you actually don't need much more than 4-6 GB of RAM per node to start, and then you can scale up if you're experiencing any slowdown. The key is simply separating these competing applications so they don't interfere with each other.